# Python: Generating absolute paths

Tags: python, directory

I need to be able to find a directory given a string ('Documents', 'Photos', etc). I can only seem to find files that are directly in the users folder (I can find the Documents folder and make a path to it, but I can't make a path to any folders inside of Documents)

```
def main():
  dir_name = sys.argv[1]
  file_path = (os.path.relpath(sys.argv[1],os.defpath))
  if(os.path.isdir(input)):
      largest_file = recursive_search(file_path)
      print("Largest file is " + largest_file)
      print("size: " + str(os.path.getsize(largest_file)))
```

My code works fine when I enter "Documents" or any other file directly under C:\Users\"username" but nothing else.

It works if I give Documents\sub-directory though I would prefer to not do that. If this stems from a misunderstanding of file systems I would be greatly appreciated for the clarification.

Comment: Also largest_file is a separate function that does what you think it does.

Comment: Why do you create a relative path instead of an absolute path?

Comment: To find a subdirectory you need to go recursively through the directories and look for it, see `os.walk()`.

Comment: Why are you using `os.defpath` (which is the default search path for executables)?

Comment: I tried to use os.walk originally however I got the same problem, it would work for Documents but not for and subdirectories. As for why I used .defpath, I was hoping that I could make a relative path to any subdirectory from the default.